# Do you know of a platform for (paid) "on-demand coding"? Like mechanical turk, but for programming tasks?

Tags: platform, marketplace

I am risking asking a "question that appears subjective"... yet I find it precise, please forgive: I was wondering whether there existed a platform where people can post a specific programming need they have, and programmers could sign up for the tasks.

I am thinking of low-skill/low-time tasks here, with money involved as well. Targeted not at professionals (who have a full-time job and enough money...), but on e.g. students with some coding skills who are happy to spend 30 minutes to implement something like "write me a Python algorithm to collect all images from this webpage" for a person not knowing Python and for e.g. 30 bucks.

Could be win-win - one guy gets his stuff done without investing much time, the other has a way to earn a few bucks in their leisure time.